# RxJava share() is not working as expected

Tags: rx-java

I have an activity where I am doing the following

```
    fun getJust(): Observable<String> {
        Log.e("TEST", "getting just")
        return Observable.just("ABC")
    }

    private fun stream(): Observable<String> {
        return getJust()
            .doOnSubscribe { Log.e("TEST", "OnSubscribe") }
            .doOnDispose { Log.e("TEST", "OnDispose") }
            .doOnNext { Log.e("TEST", "OnNext") }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val st = stream()
            .share()
        val success = st
            .map { "Success" }
        val fail = st
            .map { "Fail" }
        Observable.merge(success, fail)
            .subscribe()
    }
```

Expected Log:

```
2020-02-25 15:11:20.202 1015-1015/com.example.rxretrytest E/TEST: getting just
2020-02-25 15:11:20.263 1015-1015/com.example.rxretrytest E/TEST: OnSubscribe
2020-02-25 15:11:20.264 1015-1015/com.example.rxretrytest E/TEST: OnNext
```

Actual Log:

```
2020-02-25 15:11:20.202 1015-1015/com.example.rxretrytest E/TEST: getting just
2020-02-25 15:11:20.263 1015-1015/com.example.rxretrytest E/TEST: OnSubscribe
2020-02-25 15:11:20.264 1015-1015/com.example.rxretrytest E/TEST: OnNext
2020-02-25 15:11:20.264 1015-1015/com.example.rxretrytest E/TEST: OnSubscribe
2020-02-25 15:11:20.265 1015-1015/com.example.rxretrytest E/TEST: OnNext
```

I have the following questions:

1. Why onSubscribe/onNext are getting called twice even if I put share().
2. If I consider that it's because of Observable.just completes immediately after single emission then why not "getting just" is called twice.

Comment: "getting just" is _outside_ of the observable chain. The `getJust()` function is called only once, since `stream()` is called only once.